# variable doesn't get assigned value when inside EXECUTE IMMEDIATE when precedure is called

Tags: oracle, plsql

So, I created stored procedure (compiled without errors), but when i call it, all I get is "ORA-02216: tablespace name expected" error. Confusing thing about this is when you run this code manually, it works perfectly.
And here is the code:

```
PROCEDURE createIndexPK
IS
VAR_TABLESPACEA VARCHAR2(20);  
 BEGIN   
 SELECT MIN(TABLESPACE_NAME) INTO VAR_TABLESPACEA FROM ALL_INDEXES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SOME_TABLE';
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SOME_TABLE_PK ON SOME_TABLE
 (ID)
 LOGGING
 TABLESPACE '||VAR_TABLESPACEA||'
 PCTFREE    10
 INITRANS   2
 MAXTRANS   255
 STORAGE    (
             INITIAL          64K
             NEXT             1M
             MINEXTENTS       1
             MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
             PCTINCREASE      0
             BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
         )
 NOPARALLEL');
END;
```

Comment: Error lies with `SELECT MIN(TABLESPACE_NAME) INTO VAR_TABLESPACEA FROM ALL_INDEXES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SOME_TABLE'` Check if this query is returning anything. As per error it looks like this query is not returning any value.

Comment: I'm getting value from this one. it returns "INDEXES", which is what i need for one of situations where i'm using this

Comment: same thing, nothing changes

Comment: Which client you are using? Its working for me. Also why do you want to do this in PLSQL when you can simply use SQL

Comment: DB is 12c and client is 11.2. I need this to be stored procedure so system can run it on schedule

Comment: So debug it already. What is your question?

Comment: @William Robertson - As you can see, I accepted XINGs answer, no need to go deeper into this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am not sure why its not working for you but see a simple example where its working for me. I see the issue with your select statement but as you told that that returns value. Then probably you can try as below:

```
DECLARE
   VAR_TABLESPACEA   VARCHAR2 (20);
BEGIN
   SELECT MIN (TABLESPACE_NAME) INTO VAR_TABLESPACEA FROM ALL_INDEXES;
   --- This is not making sense to check tablespace of the table and then its minimum value
   -- WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'EMPLOYEE';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
         'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SOME_TABLE_PK ON EMPLOYEE
 (EMPLOYEE_ID)
 LOGGING
 TABLESPACE '
      || VAR_TABLESPACEA
      || '
 PCTFREE    10
 INITRANS   2
 MAXTRANS   255
 STORAGE    (
             INITIAL          64K
             NEXT             1M
             MINEXTENTS       1
             MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
             PCTINCREASE      0
             BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
         )
 NOPARALLEL';
END;
```